# prevent url string to encode & to &amp;

Tags: html, cakephp

I am using cakephp ajax pagination for my web application.

In this application i have implemented search filters also. When user filter the records, i submit the search form using GET method, in controller i get the filter variables and append them to the paginator helper like this.

```
$this->paginator->options(array(
    'url' => array_merge($this->passedArgs, array('?'=> $query_string)), 
    'update' => '#tlist', 
    'evalScripts' => true)
);
```

My problem is that in my pagination link my all & is get converted into & See below and look at the bold part.

`<a href="/sites/tutor/users/ajaxtutor/page:2?gender%5B0%5D=1`&`gender%5B1%5D=2" id="link-1795722171" />;`

And when i click on the link i do get query String as below:

```
[gender] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
[amp;gender] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )
```

how to remove this extra `amp;` from the query string.

Can anybody help how to cope with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guffa said the conversion is correct from `&`  to `&amp;` as it is html standard.

The problem was that cakephp picks pagination link's href part which contains `&amp;` in place of `&` and put it into ajax url section. See below for example:

- Pagination links:
- `<a href='somedomain.com?&amp;a=1&amp;b=2>1</a>`
- Generated ajax code:
- ```
  $("#link-1478709635").bind("click", function (event) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "somedomain.com?&amp;a=1&amp;b=2"
      });
      return false;
  ```
- And when we click on the link it will take `&amp;` in place of `&` with it.
- As a solution i used Post method in place of GET method to post my data back with pagination links in paginator options like this:
  `'data'=>http_build_query($this->request->data),`

Answer (score 2):

The `&` *should* be converted to `&amp;`. Having a `&` by itself in HTML code is incorrect.

This is what the link should look like in the HTML source:

```
<a href="/sites/tutor/users/ajaxtutor/page:2?gender%5B0%5D=1&amp;gender%5B1%5D=2" id="link-1795722171">2 </a>
```

So, if you have problems receiving the data, it's not because of the `&amp;` in the code.

Note that your keys in the query string is `gender[0]` and `gender[1]`. The HTML protocol doesn't have a concept of arrays in the query string, so that is the exact names that is delivered to the server, however PHP will then parse the values and create an array from them.

Comment: Dear Guffa, Thanks for your response. When i click on the pagination link i get extra **amp;** in my queryString key and it keep growing as i click on the pagination links.  I have edited my question, Please have a look at the get parameters and suggest how to remove this extra amp;

Comment: @Danial: The only way to get that sent in the query string would be to double encode the `&`, ending up with `&amp;amp;` or `%26amp;` in the code. Here are examples: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/4edbR/